# After a clean installation of Windows 10 Fall Creators Update - 32 bits, only boots in EFI Shell, cannot boot automatically

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

I have a Tablet with Intel Atom 32 bits processor. The eMMC is only 16GB and was almost full. On Windows Creators Update I put Windows installation on the 4GB pen drive and booted with it and formattted, and installed Windows. All OK. On BIOS it appeared as Windows Boot Manager.

Now with Fall Creators Update, the Media Creation Tool refuses my 4GB PenDrive, requires a 8GB PenDrive. I did the writing using Rufus, but now after installed, when boot, the tablet only goes to UEFI Shell. On BIOS it appears UEFI OS. When I select it, it returns to the BIOS screen. On BIOS it does appear the Windows Boot Manager option. When the installation pendrive is plugged, appears UEFI OS (SanDisk Cruzer Blade 2.01), if I remove the pendrive and reboot, then appears UEFI OS. No Windows Boot Manager.

If I enter UEFI Shell, and type

```
fs1:
cd \EFI\Boot\
bootia32.efi
```

Then the Windows starts, manually.

How to solve this? Is it some bug in this 32 bit version of Windows 10 FCU?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]