# Windows Media Creation Tool is requiring 8GB PenDrive for 32 bit version of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Windows Media Creation tool is not allowing to create Windows 32 bit media on 4GB PenDrive. 
On Creators update I could do this normally on 4GB Pen Drive. Now on Fall Creators Update, the Media Creation Tool is requiring 8GB PenDrive for 32bit only image!
I need to reinstall Windows on my 32 bit tablet using a 4GB pendrive;

See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dac269a9-168e-476a-84a5-415d75b09cba/windows-media-creation-tool-is-not-allowing-to-create-windows-32-bit-media-on-4gb-pendrive?forum=win10itprosetup

Ps:

I tried using Rufus 2.18p to Write the 32 Bits ISO on the PenDrive, using options GPT UEFI FAT32, but the Tablet does not boot from it.

If I use MBR UEFI-CSM, the tablet boots to the Windows installer, but after copy finishes, the Tablet boots to UEFI Shell. Only can enter Windows manually typing commands, see: [After a clean installation of Windows 10 Fall Creators Update - 32 bits, only boots in EFI Shell, cannot boot automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/1269145/after-a-clean-installation-of-windows-10-fall-creators-update-32-bits-only-bo)

Comment: You can try creating a slipstreamed install using NTLite and use the ISO you got as a template. It should be small enough to fit on a 4GB stick and should work with Rufus. I use that at work too, though I have plenty of 8gb and 16gb sticks, so I'm not 100% sure it works with a 4 gb stick, but I see no reason why not.

Comment: The 32 bits Windows 10 FCU ISO image already fits on 4GB pen drive. It has 2.805.399.552 bytes. I can write it with Rufus, but the Media Creation Tool still requires 8GB for this 32 bits ISO

Comment: Try the ISO to USB/DVD tool from Microsoft (Now available from CodePlex) [Create Bootable USB Flash Drive from ISO Using Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-7-usb-dvd-download-tool-bootable-flash-drive/)

Comment: @Tony, yes I know its smaller. NTLite creates a modified ISO which may work. where the normal iso don't. Its something you can try.